# when inserting php into html document, structure of elements has broken. I wanna know the reason and solution

Tags: php, html

This is my code. it works so weirdly.

```
    <a onClick="openThis('entrance', '#06C')" class="navLink" id="entrance">
        <img src="http://i1.search.daumcdn.net/s/search_all/2014/image/daumlogo_140516.gif">

        <!-- before log in -->
        <? if (!$member['mb_id']) { ?>
        <p class="navAP">
            <a href="<?=$g4['bbs_path']?>/login.php?url=<?=$urlencode?>" >로그인</a> 
            <a href="<?=$g4['bbs_path']?>/register.php">회원 가입</a>
        </p>

        <!-- after log in -->
        <? } else { ?>
        <p class="navAP"> 
            <a href="<?=$g4['bbs_path']?>/logout.php">로그아웃</a> / 
            <a href="<?=$g4['bbs_path']?>/member_confirm.php?url=register_form.php">회원 정보</a>
        </p>
        <? } ?>
    </a>
```

the structure of this sentenses are like below. It must be show like this.

```
<a>
    <img>
    <p class="navAP">
        <a></a>
        <a></a>
    </p>
</a>
```

But after coding, when I looked at the browser, it looks different with my code. 
it looks like this.

```
<a>
   <img>
</a>

<p class="navAP">
      <a></a>
      <a></a>
</p>
```

is there anyone who can solve this ploblem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
    <a onClick="openThis('entrance', '#06C')" class="navLink" id="entrance">
       <img src="http://i1.search.daumcdn.net/s/search_all/2014/image/daumlogo_140516.gif">
       <?php 
         $content = '';
         if (!$member['mb_id']){
            /* Before Log In */
            $content .= "<p class='navAP'><a href='".$g4['bbs_path']."/login.php?url=".$urlencode."'>로그인</a><a href='".$g4['bbs_path']."/register.php'>회원 가입</a></p>";
         }else{
             /* After Log In */
             $content .= "<p class='navApp'><a href='".$g4['bbs_path']."/logout.php'>로그아웃</a><a href='".$g4['bbs_path']."/member_confirm.php?url=register_form.php'>회원 정보</a></p>";
         }
         echo $content;
       ?>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6hLfe/

Loading an `a` within a `p` that is surrounded by an `a` will make the outer `a` close.

```
<a href="#"><p>Test</p></a>
<a href="#"><p><a href="#">Test</a></p></a>
```